# CFDocumentItem - change font size

Tags: coldfusion, pdf-generation, coldfusion-9

I am creating a footer in a PDF document using `<cfdocumentitem type="footer">` and it is working fine. Except that I cannot seem to control the font. I have tried `<span>`, `<font face>` etc. with no luck. Currently I am trying a table with class as below.

Anyone know how to control the font look in a footer with `<cfdocumentitem>`?

```
<cfdocument format="pdf"
        marginBottom = ".5"
        marginLeft = ".4"
        marginRight = ".4"
        marginTop = ".2"
        > 

<style type="text/css">@import "pdf.css";</style>

<cfdocumentitem type="footer">
    <cfoutput>
    <table width=100%>
        <tr>
            <td class=verd10>
                <b>#pdfstuff.pdffinal#</b>
            </td>
            <td align=right class=verd10 valign=top>
                Page #cfdocument.currentPageNumber# of #cfdocument.currentPageNumber#
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </cfoutput>
</cfdocumentitem> 

pdf document data etc

</cfdocument>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a copy of the stylesheet link **inside** the footer, like so:

```
<cfdocumentitem type="footer">
    <style type="text/css">@import "pdf.css";</style>
    <cfoutput>
        <table>
            ... etc
        </table>
    </cfoutput>
</cfdocumentitem>
```

Comment: Pulling in the @import works a little better... Get the font faces I want but not the sizes... Odd thing - I can use a .pdf12 - 12pt font in the regular pdf, but same use of font in footer is smaller - more like a 10pt, but I called the pdf12 - just seems to be restricting my size I can use in there... Wonder if marginbottom has anything to do with it too?

Comment: Yes - increasing my marginbottom to 1.5 instead of .5 changed my fontsize dramatically... It must restrict your sizes within the space allocated for marginbottom.  The @import is required as above.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to cfdocument. The only way I have been able to successfully format any text in the footer is to use a combination of html and inline styles.

Here is a footer that works for me:

```
<cfdocumentItem type="footer">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-family:Arial; font-size: 9pt;">Printed On: #dateFormat(now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")# #timeFormat(now(), "HH:MM")#</td>
            <td style="font-family:Arial; font-size: 9pt;" align="right">Page #cfdocument.currentPageNumber# of #cfdocument.totalPageCount#</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</cfdocumentItem>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is working... As always ends up same size - even if I go 10pt, 11pt etc using ur code... I wonder if it is restricted to a certain size?

Comment: hmm, I know mine worked because before I applied the style the text was HUGE.  have you tried something more obvious like color?